# Screen glitching when login user in Kubuntu 22.04 [temporary fixed?]

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, login-screen, flicker

I just getting update & the system requires me to restart. I do it like the way it told me & everything is normal.

But right after my laptop shows the user login screen, it immediately glitching so badly that i can't even see where's my mouse pointer.

I'm sure this's sofware's problem not hardware, because when i'm entering bios, the screen shows normal. Please help! I need to do lots of work!

Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad 320
OS: Kubuntu 22.04

**Edit**: i did report this as a bug yesterday to Launchpad & someone said to replace sddm to another DM. How am i suppose to do when in this condition, i can only access my BIOS?!

**UPDATE**: deperately, i run the GNU Grub by clicking shift key multiple times during booting before Kubuntu logo shows up & boot using the older kernel. The screen no longer glitching. But the latest kernel remains glitching.

here's my complete laptop specification:

- Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad 320
- Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Kernel Version: 5.15.0-84-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11
- Processors: 2 × AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G
- Memory: 7.1 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: STONEY